# Managing 3rd party JavaScript libraries in WebStorm under source control

Tags: javascript, git, typescript, nuget, webstorm

I am a newbie in WebStorm. I created a TypeScript project (empty project with enabled TypeScript transpiler) and added `index.html` with links to my scripts.

I want to add 3rd party JavaScript libraries with TypeScript declaration files (jQuery, Knockout, Snap.svg, etc), but with next requirements:

1. I don't want to add js libraries to my source control.
2. I want to have my sources in the maximum "compilable" state (minimum manipulation after git checkout).
3. Local sources (in project/external or project/libraries folder) - not all libraries have CDN.

In my fantasy it's works like a Nuget works with dll packages in Visual Studio.

Comment: You could take a look at [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [bower](http://bower.io/) or [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

They are package managers and you can use it regardless of your IDE. Adding and removing a third party library is dead easy by adding/removing a line in `bower.json`/`package.json` for `bower`/`npm` respectively.

Here's two links which could help you to learn bower.
https://css-tricks.com/whats-great-bower/
https://www.codementor.io/bower/tutorial/beginner-tutorial-getting-started-bower-package-manager